# Cannot read property 'lockDatabase' of undefined (this)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting this error because 'this' is out of scope I guess, but I can't find a way to fix it. I have tried using the fat arrow and then the function does run. But then there is the problem that I don't have a callback value that I have to use? Here is my code:

```
this.checkIfDatabaseIsLocked(function(res) {
          //If true database is locked
          console.log("result checkIfDatabaseIsLocked: " + res);
          if (res) {
            return;
          }
          //LockDatabase
          this.lockDatabase().then(
            result => {
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function here to ensure `this` remains the value you expect:

```
this.checkIfDatabaseIsLocked(res => {
      //If true database is locked
      console.log("result checkIfDatabaseIsLocked: " + res);
      if (res) {
        return;
      }
      //LockDatabase
      this.lockDatabase().then(
        result => {
... and so on
```

Comment: Oh I tried something like this, but it didn't give me back the value I need. But now it does, so perfect! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or bind your function with the correct context to get the correct `this` inside your function:

```
this.checkIfDatabaseIsLocked((res) => {
    // `this` will be bound correctly here
})
```

<strike>Or using [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):</strike>

```
this.checkIfDatabaseIsLocked((function (res) {
    // `this` will be bound correctly here
}).bind(this))
```

Don't use `Function.bind` with TypeScript. You will losing type checking. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212

Comment: There is a risk if you use `bind` in a typescript program, so you would generally avoid it. The definition of `bind` is: `bind(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;` Note that it returns `any` so you lose any type checking between the function you pass and the function signature expected by `checkIfDatabaseIsLocked`. Using the arrow function should perform the desired type checking.

Comment: I'm using the arrow function and it works great! Thanks!

Comment: That is indeed a big issue. Thanks @Duncan.